# custom list top-link-bar

Tags: custom-list, top-link-bar

I'm using SharePoint 2007, I have created Custom list.
I want to broaden the top toolbar, near to the New/Action/Setting button 
how can I create new button in the top-link-lbar?

Answer (score 1):

You want to read up on creating Custom Rendering Templates for the List Toolbar.

Here is a good blog post from MSDN on doing exactly this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedi/archive/2009/12/04/customizing-the-list-toolbar-template-wss-3-0-moss.aspx

Comment: Hi! I can use Web Part (Content Editor Web Part etc..), but I do not have the authorize for designing. do you thing that I can implement the article stage?